# Integrate google-source for Android platform libcore within an Android application

Tags: android, android-studio, java-native-interface, android-source, dalvik

The problem I am posting here about is  related to android dalvik VM. The project I am currently working on uses an existring framework. In the framework, there are some classes that are not included in Dalvik VM but Hotspot VM. So, while using that framework, I need to figure out some way to include additional Java VM class files into the mobile project. Including Java classes were no trouble at all. But some of these java classes are using some native functionalities. This is where I'm having trouble. 
There's some built-in facilities in Android studio to include native support. But I can't find a proper way to include bunch of C/C++ files in to an Android Studio module. 
Cloning the following directory gives me all the classes I need to include

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/master

I mainly need to use packages from `luni` and `ojluni` directories.

Since, I haven't worked with classes outside of the Dalvik VM, is there any way to build this whole project into a library file and add it to my android application? 
Or what is the proper way to use libraries like this into any application?

Upto now, what I've got is as follows.
Android studio allows adding native support. Creating a new project with native runs successfully and access a native method from `native-lib.cpp` and shows it in application activity.

For Android Studio to compile and add the cpp file with project, we need to add the cpp file reference in the `CMakeList.txt`

What should I do to add bunch of files, adding all these files one by one doesn’t seem like the right way to go. 
Also  in my project, I have another module (rather than app module) that I need to add the JNI support. Since there's a lot of cpp file, I can't possibly add one by one as I did with the sample  project.

Any help will really be appreciated.